# Windows10 application development: how to replace a file in localfolder

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal

I am now a student studying win10 application development using csharp and xaml, recently when i try to to choose an image in my code and later replace an existing image in my local folder, an `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` occurred. It's very confusing because i am able to modify the image file in my localfolder when i create it for the first time, but after navigating to another page and then back to this page to modify it again, it doesn't work! Can someone help me with this problem?

```
private async void select_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            BitmapImage pic = new BitmapImage();
            pic.SetSource(stream);
            this.head.Source = pic;
            StorageFolder storageFolder =
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile sampleFile =
                await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(PlayerName.Text + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await file.CopyAndReplaceAsync(sampleFile);

            //await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, PlayerName.Text + ".jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Comment: Try closing the stream first and the performing the operations on the file

Comment: I have tested your code but cannot reproduce your problem. Which code throw this exception? Are you using the same `select_Click` code after you back to this page?

Comment: the CreateFileAsync failed, i can create a new image with a new name, but cannot replace an existing image @Sunteen

Comment: it seems that the localfolder is read-only, but i have a full-control privilege.

Comment: I think i have solved the problem. i have set UriSource of an image in my UI with the same file name when i navigate to this page, so the image in my local folder is already occupied and cannot be modified again .